# Get JSON response to Angular from Flask backend

Tags: json, angularjs, flask

I want to get a JSON response from Flask backend to Angular app but could not find where the error is. The returning JSON response is:

```
{
  "phones": [
    {
    "age": 0, 
    "name": "Nexus S", 
    "snippet": "Fast just got faster with Nexus S."
    }, 
    {
    "age": 1, 
    "name": "Motorola XOOM with Wi-Fi", 
    "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation tablet."
    }, 
    {
    "age": 2, 
    "name": "MOTOROLA XOOM", 
    "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation tablet."
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the controller:

```
function Phones($scope, $http){
$http.get('127.0.0.1:5000/phones').success(function(data){
$scope.phns = data.phones;
    console.log("I'm called");
});
}
```

This works when I pass the JSON object to the controller like this:

```
$scope.phones = [
{"name": "Nexus S",
 "snippet": "Fast just got faster with Nexus S.",
 "age": 0},
{"name": "Motorola XOOM with Wi-Fi",
 "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation tablet.",
 "age": 1},
{"name": "MOTOROLA XOOM",
 "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation tablet.",
 "age": 2}
];
```

It also doesn't work when I try to get data like data.phones. I'm sure the controller gets called but the get function does not get the data somehow.

Comment: First case is an object with an array in it... second one that works shows it defined as an array... why the difference?  I guess what I'm saying is in the success you would have to assign data.phones to the $scope.phones.  Also just console.log(data) to see what you're getting.

Comment: did u get response from server

Comment: I tried data.phones also but it did not work. Visiting 127.0.0.1:5000/phones on my browser returns the json at the top. I also used flask jsonify so I think the headers should be ok. When debugging looks like success callback is not called but I could not find why.

Comment: I'm sure that the success function is not getting called. I don't know why it doesn't.

Comment: It might be easier to debug if you post the entire Angular and Flask applications you are using. I assume they are both pretty short, or you can simplify them enough to be short?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding "http" to 127.0.0.1:5000/phones should solve the problem.